# jwplayer returning function instead of player object

Tags: jwplayer

Here is my line of code: `this.player = jwplayer(this.id);`

I have two players on a page, one in an iframe. In the code I am logging the result of the jwplayer call.

The first time `jwplayer('my-video-player')` is called I get back an instantiated player that I can work with that contains the play() and pause() methods, etc. So far so good.

The next time when I call `jwplayer('my-clip-video-player')` I get back `registerPlugin: ƒ`. I can't figure out why a function call that creates a player object where the only parameter is a user-defined id doesn't return the same thing, a player instance.

Comment: https://github.com/jwplayer/jwplayer - Does the readme help you? It shows a HTML page that contains a jwplayer

Comment: No, the player is being created correctly the first time so I know I have the basics down. The second time though it fails. In the readme example it would fail because setup doesn't exist on the jwplayer('player') result. This is referring to the readme line const player = jwplayer('player').setup({ file: 'LINK_TO_YOUR_FILE.mp4' });.

Comment: Could it be that the element id does not exist that I'm passing in? i.e. id=my-clip-video-player doesn't exist on the page? I'll check this out.

Comment: Yep, I think that is what's happening. Coding a solution now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `jwplayer('my-clip-video-player')` the jwplayer call checks to make sure there is an html element with `id=my-clip-video-player`. I mistakenly had an id of something else so jwplayer had nothing to attach the player to. Changing the id in my markup to `my-clip-video-player` fixed the issue.